# ADAM bias correction derivation

Tags: neural-networks, expected-value, bias-correction, adam

[image]

Where $\beta_2\in [0,1)$ and $g_i$ is the gradient at step i.

We approximate E[gi^2] with E[gt^2] by a correction term $\zeta$. I think this is because it is assumed that the gradients are bounded. Is this correct?.

Moreover,to correct the bias, they divide by (1-$\beta_2^t$). Shouldn't they also substract $\zeta$? I don't see why is this term so small that they can discard it if the gradients are not stationary.

Comment: Notice that [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366076/understanding-a-derivation-of-bias-correction-for-the-adam-optimizer) does not solve my question, since it only solves the stationary case.